# Error al enviar emails error intento de acceder al Socket de manera prohibida asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Estoy intentando enviar correos desde un servidor cuenta de correo paga, lo cual en el local anda perfecto, el error llega cuando subo la web al servidor y este me da el siguiente error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con distintos tipos de configuraciones del smtp que al fin y al cabo terminaban en el mismo error. Supongo que deberia cambiar la ip desde la cuenta de correo pero no se como mi cuenta es de GoDaddy. Este es mi codigo...

```
private static SmtpClient EstructuraEnvios()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        Configuration c = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

        MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)c.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = settings.Smtp.Network.DefaultCredentials;
        client.Host = settings.Smtp.Network.Host;
        client.Port = settings.Smtp.Network.Port;

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Smtp.From, settings.Smtp.Network.Password);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        client.EnableSsl = settings.Smtp.Network.EnableSsl;

        return client;
    }


private static MailMessage EstructuraEmail(string asuntoEmail, string cuerpoEmail)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            Configuration c = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
            MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)c.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

            message.From = new MailAddress(settings.Smtp.From, settings.Smtp.Network.UserName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                        
            message.Subject = asuntoEmail;
            message.Body = cuerpoEmail;

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            return message;
        }

public static bool EnviarEmail(string destinatario, string asuntoEmail, string cuerpoEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage message = EstructuraEmail(asuntoEmail, cuerpoEmail);
            SmtpClient smtp = EstructuraEnvios();            

            message.To.Add(destinatario);

            smtp.Send(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```